# VBA Convert delimiter text file to Excel

Tags: excel, import, delimiter, xlsx, vba

I have a code that convert files in folder from .txt (with "|" separator) to xslx, 
But the code works fine for some files (when I open it in excel), the others are wrong, when I try to import the wring one manually by excel ribbon(Get external data -- > from text), the files are correct.

This is my code :

```
Sub tgr()

    Const txtFldrPath As String = "C:\...\txtFiles"     
    Const xlsFldrPath As String = "C:\excelFiles"     

    Dim CurrentFile As String: CurrentFile = Dir(txtFldrPath & "\" & "*.txt")
    Dim strLine() As String
    Dim LineIndex As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    While CurrentFile <> vbNullString
        LineIndex = 0
        Close #1
        Open txtFldrPath & "\" & CurrentFile For Input As #1
        While Not EOF(1)
            LineIndex = LineIndex + 1
            ReDim Preserve strLine(1 To LineIndex)
            Line Input #1, strLine(LineIndex)
        Wend
        Close #1

        With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(LineIndex, 1)
            .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strLine)
            .TextToColumns Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
        End With

        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ActiveSheet.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xlsFldrPath & "\" & Replace(CurrentFile, ".txt", ".xlsx"), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents

        CurrentFile = Dir
    Wend
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]
this picture show the result in excel and the original file .txt

Comment: And the error is -doesn't open the file? Doesn't limit it? Limit size is not the same ?- The syntax seems correct to me.

Comment: @Sgdva, I add a picture.

Comment: Are the "wrong" files from a different source?

Comment: Can you upload a working .txt file and a the non working one? I can't open DB so, preferably GDrive :)

Comment: @TimWilliams , same source

Comment: It seems that the `.TextToColumns` method fails. Did you try to do it manually (just to check if it works then). If it works manually, then record what you are doing with the macro recorder and compare the resulting code to the code in your sub. If it doesn't work then the delimiter might be incorrect. Maybe it is not a `|` which is `ChrW(124)` but maybe it is a `ChrW(9474)` (which looks very similar).

Comment: @Sgdva, yes , the Reass150616 is ok but the file AI150616 is wrong

Comment: the wrong file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6nhIMB-ueBhRzUtX2dmNl9EWkk             && the correct one : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6nhIMB-ueBhdzkzZGJLTVRjNk0

Comment: Hi @Ralph, I try to open the txt file manually and it works, You can see my 2 files and my macro where one works and the other no

Comment: There's a problem with your data in the second one, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you have bad data. There is a tab character between *Total liabilities* and *30,619,676.00* in AI060616.txt. Excel doesn't like tabs in cell content. In fact, the tab character is the default delimiter on a TextToColumns command and this translates into two column of data when the array is brought in.

```
    Open txtFldrPath & "\" & CurrentFile For Input As #1
    While Not EOF(1)
        LineIndex = LineIndex + 1
        ReDim Preserve strLine(1 To LineIndex)
        Line Input #1, strLine(LineIndex)
        'STRIP TABS OUT AND REPLACE WITH A SPACE!!!!!
        strLine(LineIndex) = Replace(strLine(LineIndex), Chr(9), Chr(32))
    Wend
    Close #1
```

Next, the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) 'remembers' all of the settings that were used the last time it was run through; it doen't matter whether that was by the user on hte worksheet or through VBA. You need many more parameters than you have supplied in order to guarantee that it is going to operate the way you want.

```
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(LineIndex, 1)
        .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strLine)
        'DEFINE THE OPERATION FULLY!!!!
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                       Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                       Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    End With
```

[image: import_TXT]

Answer (score 1):

While I do not understand the solution / problem yet, it seems that it is solved if you apply the `.TextToColumns` method twice:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(LineIndex, 1)
    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strLine)
    .TextToColumns Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    .TextToColumns Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
End With
```

Maybe someone else can clarify why that is. While this is not the kind of post I normally provide, the above should give you a workaround while someone else comes up with a better solution (including an explanation).

Comment: It's not the problem, the problem is that the "raw" data has 2 columns, excel can't delimit when source data has 2 columns.

Comment: Even the solution is a work-around, the data is compromised, probably the best approach would be to fix the "raw" data so delimit can work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The file AI150616 has in the column "B" the data 
`30,619,676.00 Net worth = ZAR 83,456,466.00 Hence, final required BG should be (63,503,915.82)`
 
[image]
 Delimiter only works with one column. 
Should that be allowable? If not, another procedure may be needed to check if data is correct , if so, append it, else, warn the user data has been compromised somehow.

Comment: The file text is the problem...The client send data to DB and we extract data in .txt, I didn't see that in the data the is some tab, and the extraction was made by pipes ...   anyway, the solution above solved the problem. thanks everybody