# Importing some parts of a lot of text files to excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text

I am new to VBA so I need your advices. I need to read data from a lot of text files into excel. Text files are like that: [image]

What I have to do is, I need to read every files' all Feature types and parametres actual values. The format of excel should be like that:[image]

I tried some codes by adapting to my situation but I couldn't do. Do you have an advice about how can I do that? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should post your code first, so others could try to figure what the problem is.  Anyway the source file is hard to analyze as it's not following any program format.  (e.g. are all the fields separated by tabs?)

Comment: My code is very useless, I've done it by recording a macro and opening one of the text files, after that copying and pasting cells. This is my main problem. My source file is not following any program format. I tried to do that by opening text files in excel and changing positions of cells. But there are more than 4000 text files so It is hard to open all of them in excel.

Comment: Is your posted text file the *actual file* or have you generalized the content? Are all files formatted exactly the same with the same number of fields ? Can you post an example file somewhere where it can be downloaded ?

Comment: If text files are TAB delimited then u can split the text into column at each TAB using text to column option...please check this link for vba solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843318/7889129)

Comment: I generalized the content.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/33p6xwtpblzpdm6/sample.txt?dl=0 here is the link of my file. @Tim Williams

Comment: OK - this will not be a very simple task to do reliably, and would be more or less difficult depending on the variability/consistency in your files.  If you're not that familiar with coding then I'd consider hiring someone for the task.

Comment: I am familiar with coding but not with vba. Do you have any suggestion about how can I start? @Tim Williams

Comment: Start with how to read a text file line-by-line in VBA - you can use either the "built-in" methods, or some people find the `FileSystemObject` methods easier to work with. Then you can use methods like `Split()` and `Instr()` to find the pieces of the content you need, based on the location of "known" content (such as "Feature1", "Feature2" etc)

Comment: Can you share a sample code that I can start with? @Tim Williams

Comment: Also, I need to read a lot of text files line by line, not one file. How can I read them line by line with FileSystemObject method? @TimWilliams

Comment: it might be easier to do this with Power Query than with VBA. But either way, there will be a learning curve. This is not a free code writing service, so you'll need to make your own start and post a question when you are stuck on a specific problem, not the general approach. You should work out the general approach yourself. On paper, with words. Then translate that into the coding language.

Comment: *How can I read them line by line*  Go through the documentation for the FileSystemObject and that method will be presented, along with others.

Comment: "I need to read a lot of text files line by line, not one file" - if you can read one file, you can read many files (assuming they all follow the same pattern).  The main challenge here is to figure out that first file ;-)